# Cannot reach values in map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I'm trying to map through an array and pass data to a React component. I get my data from a headless CMS and can see an array with a length of 8 when trying to console.log the array I am trying to map. However when I try to get the data inside of map loop I get undefined for all data points.

My attempt:

```
  {data.sanityCourses.courses.map(({ node }, index) => (
        <CourseBlockFetcher data={node} index={index}  formData={data.sanityCourses} />
      ))}
```

If I run console.log outside the map using `{console.log("Console log outside of the map: ", data.sanityCourses.courses)}` I can see all the values, see attached screenshot
[image: Image showing console log with 8 array values being returned]

But running console.log inside the map like so `console.log("inside the map", node)` only returns undefined. How ever I get 8 instances of "undefined", so the map loops through the correct number of items; but cannot see any of the data. Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds like it's being populated asynchronously, but there's not enough code here to say what a fix would be

Comment: You are destructuring a `node` property from each element. From the first console.log there is no `node` property